# Angular Service Callback Command Composition

Tags: angular, typescript

### Setup

I have been working on an API for creating dynamic keyboard shortcuts that can work for any given Angular Component. Here is the model used to represent a `Shortcut`:

```
export class Shortcut {
  keyCode: number;
  command: Function;
  args?: any;

  constructor(keyCode: number, command: Function, args?: any[]) {
    this.keyCode = keyCode;
    this.command = command;
    if (args) {
      this.args = args;
    }
  }
}
```

The intended use is as follows:

```
// function called in component OnInit function
initializeShortcuts() {
    this.shortcutService
        .addShortcut(
            KeyCodes.One, 
            this.md.createMarkdown, 
            [this.mdEditor, '#']
         );      
}
```

In the component template, the `keydown` event is checked against a textarea, which in turn calls a `checkShortcut` function on the `ShortcutService`. Here is the entire service:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Shortcut } from './shortcut';


@Injectable()
export class ShortcutService {
  shortcuts = new Array<Shortcut>();

  checkShortcut(event: KeyboardEvent) {
    if (event.ctrlKey) {
      const result = this.shortcuts.filter((s: Shortcut) => {
        return s.keyCode === event.keyCode;
      })[0];

      if (result) {
        console.log(result);
        event.preventDefault();
        result.args ? result.command(...result.args) : result.command();
      }
    }
  }

  addShortcut(keyCode: number, command: Function, args?: any[]) {
    this.shortcuts.push(new Shortcut(keyCode, command, args));
  }

  removeShortcut(shortcut: Shortcut) {
    const index = this.shortcuts.indexOf(shortcut);
    this.shortcuts.splice(index, 1);
  }
}
```

### Problem

As I have it now, it works, but I have to explicitly define any supporting functions within the callback function itself as the `this` context is unavailable, as seen in the `MarkdownService`:

```
createMarkdown(editor: ElementRef, markdown: string) {
    function getEditorValues(editor: ElementRef): EditorValues {
      return new EditorValues(
        editor.nativeElement.selectionStart,
        editor.nativeElement.selectionEnd,
        editor.nativeElement.value.length,
        editor.nativeElement.value
      );
    }

    const values = getEditorValues(editor);

    if (values.start === values.end) {
      editor.nativeElement.value = `${values.zeroToStart}${markdown}${values.startToLength}`;
    } else {
      editor.nativeElement.value =  `${values.zeroToStart}${markdown}${values.startToLength}`;
    }
}
```

If I define `getEditorValues()` in the service itself and reference that function call when assigning the `values` constant, an error is thrown because the object is undefined.

Is there a better approach to accomplishing something like this where dependent functionality can be accessed outside of the callback function?

See [StackBlitz Project](https://stackblitz.com/edit/markdown-editor?file=app%2Fapp.component.ts) for example.

Comment: is https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind perhaps what you are looking for? You can bind a context to the callback.

Comment: Honestly, I'm having a hard time following along and understanding the problem explained in your problem section.  However if I understand your problem with the binding of `this` being lost when you pass a function of an object, instead of passing the function to your add shortcut, wrap it in an arrow function to keep the `this` context.

Comment: Thanks @httpNick, `bind` did end up being part of the solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can keep the `this` context of a function by wrapping it with an arrow function. Instead of passing this:

```
this.md.createMarkdown
```

Pass the following:

```
(...params) => this.md.createMarkdown(...params)
```

Or you can bind the `this` instead by passing the following:

```
this.md.createMarkdown.bind(this)
```

Comment: Thanks a ton for this! The problem I was having was indeed related to specifying the `this` context, and this was just what I needed. The second approach that you proposed worked great because it allows me to specify the context of `this`. In the first instance, I would have been limited to the context of the calling component. The result ended up being `this.md.createMarkdown.bind(this.md)`.